# CSS/JQuery extractor is extracting default value in case of load test, for the random threads

Tags: jmeter

Performing a login and update user test with multiple users.

I have created a CSV file with 200 username and passwords. Running 200 threads

Performing login and update user, with 200 users.

I am extracting the value of **csrf** token in a variable after the login request. Then, I am passing that **csrf** variable in the user update, post request.

Running the same request with 100 users, I am able to log in and update the user's details.

Running the same request with 200 users.

1. getting the connection timeout exception.
2. Some of the update user post requests are getting failed because **csrf** variable is extracting the default values of CSS/JQuery extractor. CSRF token actual value is not getting extracted to the variable.

I have also added Authorization, Cookie, Cache and Header Manager in my test plan.
The constant timer is also being used after login request.

I have set the value of timeouts to **120000** in the HTTP request defaults. Even if I am increasing the timeouts, getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your application under test simply gets overloaded therefore it cannot respond in a timely fashion.

With regards to CSS/JQuery extractor which is failing to get CSRF token - my expectation is that the token is not present in the response for failing samplers.

So I would recommend taking the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Completely remove Connect and Response timeouts in the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so JMeter will wait for response forever.
2. Configure JMeter to save responses for failed samplers by adding the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```

   this way you will be able to see how does response look like for failing requests. See [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) User Manual chapter to learn what other metrics could be useful for your analysis.
3. Check your application and middleware (web/application/database server/load balancer logs)
4. Make sure to set up monitoring of baseline OS health metrics on the application under test side. You can do this using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
5. Just in case double check you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri T. But why the extractor is passing a default value to the variable in some cases. I have increased the time value in constant timer, for post-login and update requests but facing the same issue.

Default value of extractor is being passed in 8 to 10 user update request out of 200 users.


Please suggest if missing something.

Comment: My expectation is that in these "some cases" the response simply doesn't  contain required CSRF token